# How to disable italics for \textgreek in .bib output

Tags: biblatex, biber, greek, italic

I would like to disable the italics for the titles in Greek from my .bib file, but not for the entire document. How should I do?

I believe that the best way is to use `\emph{}` with Greek characters when needed without using `\textgreek{}` [I need italics for Greek only a few times], and to disable italics options for `\textgreek{}`, but I don't know how to do the last operation in the preamble of the main document.

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT
% !TeX root = Italics.tex
% !BIB TS-program = biber


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
    \setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
    \setotherlanguages{latin,greek,english,german,russian,serbian}
        \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}


\usepackage[style=phys, sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}

\emph{ἄνθρωπος}

\printbibliography[keyword=regular,title={Bibliography}]
\nocite{*}


\end{document}
```

---

```
@book{Sathas.1872,
 editor = {Sathas, Konstantinos N.},
 year = {1872-1894},
 title = {\textgreek{Μεσαιωνικὴ Βιβλιοθήκη. Συλλογὴ ἀνεκδότων μνημείων τῆς Ἑλλενικῆς ἱστορίας}},
 volumes = {I-VII},
 address = {\textgreek{Παρίσι}},
 publisher = {\textgreek{Ἑταιρεία Μακεδονικῶν Σπουδῶν}}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the title formatting only for a certain language, you need to set the `languageid` in the entry and check for it in the formatting command with `\iffieldequalstr`.

In `SathasA` the field `languageid` is set to `greek` while in `SathasB` the field is completely omitted:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{SathasA,
    editor = {Sathas, Konstantinos N.},
    date = {1872},
    title = {Μεσαιωνικὴ Βιβλιοθήκη. Συλλογὴ ἀνεκδότων μνημείων τῆς Ἑλλενικῆς ἱστορίας},
    volumes = {I-VII},
    address = {Παρίσι},
    publisher = {Ἑταιρεία Μακεδονικῶν Σπουδῶν},
    langid = {greek}
  }
  @book{SathasB,
    editor = {Sathas, Konstantinos N.},
    date = {1872},
    title = {Μεσαιωνικὴ Βιβλιοθήκη. Συλλογὴ ἀνεκδότων μνημείων τῆς Ἑλλενικῆς ἱστορίας},
    volumes = {I-VII},
    address = {Παρίσι},
    publisher = {Ἑταιρεία Μακεδονικῶν Σπουδῶν},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
  \setmainlanguage{italian}
    \setotherlanguages{greek,english}
      \setkeys{greek}{variant=polytonic}

\usepackage[style=phys, sorting=none]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{% <-- change the format of the title field
    \iffieldequalstr{langid}{greek}{\normalfont{#1}}{\mkbibitalic{#1}}}
    % if langid = greek, then use \normalfont else use \mkbibitalic
  
\begin{document}

\emph{ἄνθρωπος} \autocite{SathasA}
\emph{ἄνθρωπος} \autocite{SathasB}
\printbibliography[title={Bibliography}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want the whole citation in greek (translated strings, etc.), then add the biblatex option `autolang=other`:

[image]

Comment: In this way, are the titles in Latin characters still with italics or not? I would like to disable the italics for the Greek only.

Comment: @Giacomo - Only greek entries are upright

Comment: Thank you. Why the n.1 is upright and the n.2 is in italics?

Comment: The first citation has the field `languageid = {greek}` which is responsible for the upright title. In the second case the `languageid` is not set, therefor it remains italicised